# Suppressing instruction reordering in the WindRiver (Diab) Compiler

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I am searching for the proper and accepted way to inhibit instruction reordering in the WindRiver C compiler (AKA Diab C (?)). The problem is that I have to write hardware registers several times within the same function and I don't want the optimizer to reorder the sequence or worse, to collect multiple writes into one. Please do not recommend "volatile" as I don't want to rely on this invisible and unreliable prerequisite (mostly because the definition may not be under my control). I am currently using an empty inline assembler-statement:

```
 asm volatile (" ");
```

as surrogate because the compiler docs say that this will prevent reordering, OTOH maybe there is a more common way which every decent user of WindRiver C should know of.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already verified that such reordering is taking place? You could also turn off optimizations for this one translation unit.

Comment: The point is that I must release this code as source, so any fix that just circumvents the problem by setup, external definitions or other non-binding (at the compile level) measures will not work.

Comment: I do not use the Windriver compiler, but on many others i have used there are compiler specific instructions (pragmas) that let you disable optimizations from within the source code. I'd look in your compiler handbook for those.

Comment: Ok, so I still can't help myself from saying that this is *exactly* the use case `volatile` was designed for. What is the problem?

Comment: @BoPersson: while you are correct, I don't have control over the definition and I generally try to avoid "volatile" as the only technical solution to optimization dangers. Its importance is hardly ever visible at the location where its nature (in our case: executing accesses to the object in the same order like the abstract machine) comes into play and most C programmers still erroneously read "ah! mutex!" when seeing volatile. So I would like to have something in the instruction sequence visible to make clear that sequence matters there. Currently a "REORDER_BARRIER()" fills the gap.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with WindRiver, but this situation should come up in any self optimizing PowerPC type processor and compiler.  The IBM and Motorola compilers include the assembler instruction (I m not making this up) `eieio`.  Enforce In-Order Execution of I/O.  You need to wrap an `eieio` around every single write to a hardware register so making a regWrite() macro is a good idea.  And, no, volatile won't fix the problem since powerPC processors are bright enough to ignore repeated instructions without the help of the compiler.